# ESC/POS need to get outline and font size working, having no luck

Tags: hex, escpos

I have a Brother QL820nwb I only need to to print via bluetooth using ESC/POS and my brain hurts trying to get it working. I have been able to get the printer to change orientation of the numbers. I tried to change to outline font so I can print at like 233 char size. Been hours without any luck, any help would be great.

### I'm sending the following.

1. orientation
2. outline font ?
3. font size ?
4. text I need to printer very large.

   ```
        \x1b\x69\x4C\x01
        \x1B\x6B\x11
        \x1B\x58\x01\x48\x01
        892807
   ```

Comment: this is the document I'm using if this helps, https://download.brother.com/welcome/docp100306/cv_ql820_eng_escp_101.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The numerical value of each parameter described in the specification is a decimal number, so you need to convert it to a hexadecimal number in the format you code.

2.outline font

```
\x1B\x6B\x11
```

If you specify Helsinki, this is the format.

```
\x1B\x6B\x0B
```

3.font size

```
\x1B\x58\x01\x48\x01
```

If you want to specify 233 times in the outline font, this is the format.

```
\x1B\x58\x00\xE9\x00
```

Comment: its bigger but not by much anyway to make the text fill the whole label? thanks for the details btw it did help.

Comment: I don't think this is working if I add that vs another font size its still the same size nothing changes. You sure thats correct? font size does not appear to change.

Comment: Please change the type of outline font, change the magnification to a small size so that it fits on the paper, or start a new line in advance so that the enlarged part fits on the paper and prepare a margin in the upward direction before printing. Please try various things.

Comment: thanks kunif; I would love to do this I have no idea this is just for my home office not really my area. If you don't mind showing me the codes; totally willing to pay to have this done I can shoot you $100 if that helps me get this working.

Comment: Is it possible to use manuals, tools, and SDKs provided by vendors? Or ask the support desk and it shouldn't be difficult to get an answer. [Printing by Directly Sending Commands](https://www.brother.co.jp/eng/dev/print/command/index.aspx), [QL-820NWB Manuals](https://support.brother.com/g/b/manualtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=lpql820nwbeus), [QL-820NWB Downloads](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=lpql820nwbeus)